# Is there any way to pass a long javascript array to a python script which is using python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi, stringify

> I am creating a webpage with submit button.
> Once user will click on submit button all checkboxes values selected by user will be stored in java script array and will be passed onto a python script argument (which is a callback of onlick function of submit button).

These all values are getting passed in the URL of the next webpage and the huge character length of argument value for python script is leading into error 403 (Requested URL too long).
This is the snipped of the code which i have.
Below is javscript function which is called when submit button is clicked and then it will redirect to next page with all the arguments.

```
function joinAllVal() {
    var tempList =[];
    var maxRow = 50;
    for ( var item = 1; item < maxRow;item++){
        var t1 =document.getElementByName(`cb_${item}`).value;
        tempList.push(t1);
    }
    var suffix = "inpList="+tempList;
    var nextPagePyUrl = "new.py?"+suffix;
    location.href=nextPagePyUrl;
}
```

```
HTML part: <button onclick="joinAllVal()" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

Error: Request -URI Too Long